# php can't access global variable outside of function

Tags: php, variables, global

I'm trying to access the PHP variables `$error_message` and `$success_message` outside of the `check_fields` function. It's not working. I understand that using globals isn't recommended. I just need a way to either return the variables and the boolean `true` or `false` or get them globally.

```
function check_fields($pattern,$post,$minlength,$maxlength,$name_of_field)
{
    global $error_message;
    global $success_message;
    $length_of_string = strlen($post);
    if(isset($post))
    {
        if(preg_match($pattern,$post))
        {
            if($minlength < $length_of_string || $maxlength > $length_of_string)
            {
                return true;
                $success_message .= $name_of_field . ' checked successfully...';
            }else
                {
                return false;
                $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' must be less than ' . $maxlength . 'and greater than' . $minlength;
                }

        }else 
        {
        return false;
            $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' was not correct, please enter this information again <br />';
        }

    }else
    {
        return false;
        $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' was not set <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: "Outside of the function" isn't always the same as global scope. Each function call *layer* has its own local scope. So it depends on what else happened till your function was reached, and *where* you're trying to access that shared variable.

Comment: What would you recommend I do then?

Comment: return an object or an array with a response(boolean) and a message(string) field

Comment: Put the `return false` statements _after_ the `$error_message .= $name_of_field ...` statements. Currently they are unreachable. Nothing to do with the `global` variable references.

Comment: Ryan thank you so much, you solved my problem. All of the rest of you, great answers. I will look into all of your answers more soon.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create the variables outside your function. (Since you don't include that code, I can't tell if you have already done this.)

You also need to put your message into those fields before you "return false." In the code you posted, most of your message assignment statements are unreachable.

```
$error_message = '';
$success_message = '';

function check_fields($pattern,$post,$minlength,$maxlength,$name_of_field)
{
    global $error_message;
    global $success_message;
    $length_of_string = strlen($post);
    if(isset($post))
    {
        if(preg_match($pattern,$post))
        {
            if($minlength <= $length_of_string)
            {
                //return true;
                $success_message .= $name_of_field . ' checked successfully...';
                return true;
            }else
                {
                //return false;
                $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' must be less than ' . $maxlength . 'and greater than' . $minlength;
                return false;
                }

        }else 
        {
            //return false;
            $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' was not correct, please enter this information again ';
            return false;
        }

    }else
    {
        //return false;
        $error_message .= $name_of_field . ' was not set';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All good answers and you guys are brilliant, but the one that seems the most feasible to implement so far was just adjusting the precedence of the boolean true false statements. I guess the code was like exiting before it was able to record the error message. Thanks to all of you, but the answer I've gone with is by Ryan Vincent.